# Unable to login into OAuth2.0 authenticated website using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth-2.0

I cannot login inside site with OAuth 2.0 protocol using Python.

The site URL format is

```
https://<site_name>/login?state=hKFo2SBvbWlEZXM5VEZ4S0FESXl2eE1KSHhUbWZ0RTJMZEN6eqFupWxvZ2luo3RpZNkgMGkwMFhBTVFJdFB1b3d6Y1pjN3RaTFAxNks4X1ozRXOjY2lk2SBYODdZQU5xTHF5M3JXYmxqM3FZVnhBNUFlazE1bmxkaw&client=X87YANqLqy3rWblj3qYVxA5Aek15nldk&protocol=oauth2&prompt=login&response_type=token id_token&redirect_uri=<redirect uri>Fcallback&scope=openid profile email&audience=https:%2F%2Fprod-api.site.com&app_name=<name>&page_mode=legacy&init_username=&view=login&email_readonly=false&nonce=Uqm-GqGpGc5hfKHoIZzwNXUHKPdpHmob&auth0Client=eyJuYW1lIjoiYXV0aDAuanMiLCJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiOS4xOS4wIn0%3D&capturedTime=1685257511244
```

How can I login into this site with Python?

I am trying to login into the website, which is using OAuth 2.0 as the login authenticator. I tried Selenium but after login it redirects to the error page instead of the redirect URI. Also that site doesn't provide an API key and secret.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.